# Not able to see option to flag as duplicate

Tags: support, flags, duplicate-questions

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45674317/if-hasclass-keep-it-if-has-not-add-it) question. It seemed duplicate of existing questions. So I decided to flag it, but wasn't able to see any option to flag as `a duplicate`. Only options I got were as below - 
[image]
Hence chose the third option, added links to duplicate in as a note for reviewer and as a comment below question too.

Although the post has been Closed. My flag has been rightfully declined asking me to use correct category.

**Was it a bug or am I missing something here ?**

Note - But, now when I try on any new questions, I'm able to see all options including the `a duplicate`.

Comment: You can't flag it for closure because it's already closed.

Comment: @Servy The situation I described was before it was closed.

Comment: No, it wasn't.  It was closed at the time.  That's why the option wasn't there.  It may have just recently been closed, but it was closed.

Comment: Oh I see. so it means - it didn't reflected on the UI, but if I would have done a page refresh then would have been able to see it as closed ?

Answer (score 4):

That question is already closed (as a duplicate, but that doesn't matter – it could've been closed as off-topic, that wouldn't have made a difference).

Therefore, you can't close it again as a duplicate of another question. It needs to be reopened first for that to happen.

> Hence chose the third option, added links to duplicate in as a note for reviewer and as a comment below question too.

The third option doesn't add the question to the review queue, but sends it straight away to a special queue for ♦ moderators. In general, you shouldn't do this for closing questions; that's something the community can do on its own, and you should stick to standard flags.

Comment: The situation I'm describing was before it was closed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was closed the moment you hit the flag link.

Comment: For what it's worth: moderators will absolutely decline custom flags asking us to close a question as a duplicate...unless you give us a very good reason. An example of a good reason might be that the question is already closed for some other reason, but you think it would be better to close it as a duplicate. Speaking for me personally, at least, I might disagree with you, but would still mark such a flag as "helpful", since it *isn't* something that you could handle using a standard flag or any standard mechanism (other than re-opening and closing again, which doesn't work).

Comment: Changed September 2023:  I'm now seeing a popup "This question is now closed - please refresh the page for updated status." instead of the confusing partial list of flags.  Much better.