# Should there be a text reply option for private feedback like "A community member has suggested a similar question"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

My feature request is to be able to respond with a text reply instead of just yes / no to the private feedback marker/flag.  At least for me the answer could be "no, because X" or "maybe, because Y".

My question (if it doesn't end up closed and deleted) - ["Needs Improvement" reason is missing from flag choices](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426247/needs-improvement-reason-is-missing-from-flag-choices)

This received private feedback asking if it should be considered a duplicate of [Not able to see option to flag as duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/not-able-to-see-option-to-flag-as-duplicate)

The answer I wanted to give is:

Maybe.  The answer is the same to both questions, but the keyword search for one may not find the other because "flag" by itself will turn up too many answers to sift through and phrases "duplicate" and "needs improvement" will only find one of the two.

In this case I'm fine with my answer being closed, though I think that will make it less likely someone else will find the answer.

In other cases, someone might want to say something like (in SO proper) "no, that is the an older version of the API and the answer uses a function that was removed".

Comment: @Makyen's answer below makes the process much more clear.  I think the process is a little unclear for lower rep people like me who don't see the other side, so a better feature request might be for another link in the "is this a duplicate?" box that explains more about it?  Actually, the explanation box once it *is* closed as a dup is perfectly clear, just (to me) not the pre-closure question box.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there shouldn't be a *private* way to respond, because that would be negative for you, the question author.

Question closure and voting to close is public. Anyone with > 3k reputation can vote to close or reopen. If you responded privately to such a suggestion, your private reply is near-useless. It *might* get that single close-voter to reconsider their, personal, close-vote, but it wouldn't provide any information to anyone else who might consider voting to close. Any response should be public, so other potential close-voters can see. In general, you should be *editing your question* to make it more clear why it's not a duplicate (e.g. provide more context that makes it clearly a separate, non-duplicate question).

In addition, that "private feedback" suggesting a potential duplicate isn't actually private. Whenever someone votes or flags to close a question as a duplicate, there's a comment that's automatically posted on the question indicating the suggestion for a duplicate. The "owner/author" of that comment is the person who voted/flagged to close, so that user could choose to delete that comment in order to keep the fact that they voted/flagged to close private until such time as the question is closed. It's also possible for the comment to be deleted by flags and/or a moderator, but both of those are unlikely.

Overall, it's absolutely not in your best interest to have a *private* reply or edit to your question in response to a suggestion that your question should be closed.

Comment: Thanks, my SO rep is only 1.4K so I have no experience with the other side of closing or deleting questions.    From the non-moderation side seeing what looks like a private message about a possible duplicate looks like something where a no response would go to that person and you'd want to explain why